# Should I see flags?

Tags: support, flags, meta, privileges, 10k-tools

It's been a long journey. I can finally handle flags....or can I?

Is there some kind of delay? Should I see them somewhere? I even flagged the formatting sandbox to see it and see my options. None. Actually, nothing seem to have changed at all.

(I do see deleted posts though)

Where are my permissions?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools

Comment: @Door thanks. It should be integrated somewhere in the UI.

Comment: It, is, but currently you can't see it because there aren't any flags to handle :P

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow Thats why. Thanks.

Comment: You can always get there by clicking on the review link in the top bar, and then clicking on "Tools" in the header/title of that page (right above the list of queues).

Comment: Frankly, given the low flag count, the biggest benefit of the 10K privilege on MSO/MSE is not the moderation (since most of that is handled by diamond mods and 3K users).  It is the ability to finally see all of the deleted answers and not have broken "10K only" links.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking as a relatively new 10Ker on meta who doesn't have 10K privileges on another site, I went through the same wondering you are going through a few months ago.

Basically, flags are few and far between here on meta.  I think this has a lot to do with the looser rules on meta, the lower question volume, plus the higher level of self moderation that goes on and the fact that users tend to be more familiar with the SE model and don't make as many mistakes that need flags to clean up.  I do see flags regularly, but not always every day, and I don't think I've ever seen more than 2 flags at the same time.

When there are flags in the queue, you will see a redish-orange box with a number in the topbar:

> [image: TopBar with location of flag field circled]

Accessing the 10K tools is less obvious. You can also access them from the review page by clicking the "Tools" link

> [image: 10K Tools link from review page]

And from there, you can access all of the goodies:

> [image: 10K Tools]

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about here on Meta, there are currently no flags for you to see. The only flags 10k users have access to see are NAA, VLQ, and a few of the automated flags (like excessively long). Everything else is reserved for moderators only.

Comment: Awww the deception :( haha thanks.